# In which case do you use the JPA @JoinTable annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, hibernate-mapping

In which case do you use the JPA `@JoinTable` annotation?

Answer (score 442, accepted):

**EDIT 2017-04-29**: As pointed to by some of the commenters, the `JoinTable` example does not need the `mappedBy` annotation attribute. In fact, recent versions of Hibernate refuse to start up by printing the following error:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: 
   Associations marked as mappedBy must not define database mappings 
   like @JoinTable or @JoinColumn
```

---

Let's pretend that you have an entity named `Project` and another entity named `Task` and each project can have many tasks.

You can design the database schema for this scenario in two ways.

The first solution is to create a table named `Project` and another table named `Task` and add a foreign key column to the task table named `project_id`:

```
Project      Task
-------      ----
id           id
name         name
             project_id
```

This way, it will be possible to determine the project for each row in the task table. If you use this approach, in your entity classes you won't need a join table:

```
@Entity
public class Project {

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project")
   private Collection<Task> tasks;

}

@Entity
public class Task {

   @ManyToOne
   private Project project;

}
```

The other solution is to use a third table, e.g. `Project_Tasks`, and store the relationship between projects and tasks in that table:

```
Project      Task      Project_Tasks
-------      ----      -------------
id           id        project_id
name         name      task_id
```

The `Project_Tasks` table is called a "Join Table". To implement this second solution in JPA you need to use the `@JoinTable` annotation. For example, in order to implement a uni-directional one-to-many association, we can define our entities as such:

**`Project` entity:**

```
@Entity
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long pid;

    private String name;

    @JoinTable
    @OneToMany
    private List<Task> tasks;

    public Long getPid() {
        return pid;
    }

    public void setPid(Long pid) {
        this.pid = pid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Task> getTasks() {
        return tasks;
    }

    public void setTasks(List<Task> tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }
}
```

**`Task` entity:**

```
@Entity
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long tid;

    private String name;

    public Long getTid() {
        return tid;
    }

    public void setTid(Long tid) {
        this.tid = tid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

This will create the following database structure:

[image: ER Diagram 1]

The `@JoinTable` annotation also lets you customize various aspects of the join table. For example, had we annotated the `tasks` property like this:

```
@JoinTable(
        name = "MY_JT",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "PROJ_ID",
                referencedColumnName = "PID"
        ),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "TASK_ID",
                referencedColumnName = "TID"
        )
)
@OneToMany
private List<Task> tasks;
```

The resulting database would have become:

[image: ER Diagram 2]

Finally, if you want to create a schema for a many-to-many association, using a join table is the only available solution.

Comment: using the first approach I have my Project filled with my tasks and each Task filled with parent Project before the merge and works but all my entries are duplicated based on the number of my tasks. A Project with two tasks are saved twice in my database. Why ?

Comment: **UPDATE**
There aren't duplicates entries in my database, the hibernate is selecting with the left outer join and I dont know why..

Comment: I believe `@JoinTable/@JoinColumn` can be annotated on same field with `mappedBy`.  So the correct example should be keeping the `mappedBy` in `Project`, and move the `@JoinColumn` to `Task.project`  (or vice-versa)

Comment: How do I insert new rows in to Join table? Through an independent Entity for the join table?

Comment: Is the `@ManyToOne private Project project;` required in the `Task` entity for the mapping to work in `Project`?  I see this in just about every Spring example and find that a child linking back to its parent creates too much dependency.

Comment: Nice! But I have a further question: if the join table `Project_Tasks` needs the `name` of `Task` as well, which becomes three columns: `project_id`,`task_id`,`task_name`, how to achieve this?

Comment: One of the clearest and simplest examples on the topic and actually on anything related to JPA and Entity-beans. I've wondered why people have to make complex examples on this topic always. +1

Comment: I think you should not have mappedBy on your second usage example to prevent this error `Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Associations marked as mappedBy must not define database mappings like @JoinTable or @JoinColumn:`

Comment: This wont work until you change 
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "project") 
to
@OneToMany in the latter case

Comment: I think this answer should be edited since it misguides the reader about usage of mappedBy in the JoinTable annotation. The other user have also mentioned this.

Comment: @karthikm So where should we put `mappedBy` and why?

Comment: +1 best explanation I have seen. Just make it clear that the tasks property for join table is on the Project entity.

Comment: Question: what if i have already this additional table? The JoinTable wont overwrite the existign one right?

Comment: @TheWandererr If you use Hibernate, that depends on what `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` configuration you choose: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#schema-generation. Other JPA implementations should have similar properties.

Comment: @Behrang i am using Spring MVC and the ddl is not set on auto

Comment: @TheWandererr Spring MVC, or Spring in general, by default uses Hibernate as the JPA provider. You can configure Hibernate's behaviour as documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-hibernate).

Answer (score 31):

### `@ManyToMany` associations

Most often, you will need to use `@JoinTable` annotation to specify the mapping of a many-to-many table relationship:

- the name of the link table and
- the two Foreign Key columns

So, assuming you have the following database tables:

[image: Many-to-many table relationship]

In the `Post` entity, you would map this relationship, like this:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {
    CascadeType.PERSIST,
    CascadeType.MERGE
})
@JoinTable(
    name = "post_tag",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "post_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")
)
private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();
```

The `@JoinTable` annotation is used to specify the table name via the `name` attribute, as well as the Foreign Key column that references the `post` table (e.g., `joinColumns`) and the Foreign Key column in the `post_tag` link table that references the `Tag` entity via the `inverseJoinColumns` attribute.

> Notice that the cascade attribute of the `@ManyToMany` annotation is set to `PERSIST` and `MERGE` only because cascading `REMOVE` is a bad idea since we the DELETE statement will be issued for the other parent record, `tag` in our case, not to the `post_tag` record.

### Unidirectional `@OneToMany` associations

The unidirectional `@OneToMany` associations, that lack a `@JoinColumn` mapping, behave like many-to-many table relationships, rather than one-to-many.

So, assuming you have the following entity mappings:

```
@Entity(name = "Post")
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
 
    private String title;
 
    @OneToMany(
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<PostComment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
 
    //Constructors, getters and setters removed for brevity
}
 
@Entity(name = "PostComment")
@Table(name = "post_comment")
public class PostComment {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
 
    private String review;
 
    //Constructors, getters and setters removed for brevity
}
```

Hibernate will assume the following database schema for the above entity mapping:

[image: Unidirectional @OneToMany JPA association database tables]

As already explained, the unidirectional `@OneToMany` JPA mapping behaves like a many-to-many association.

To customize the link table, you can also use the `@JoinTable` annotation:

```
@OneToMany(
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
    orphanRemoval = true
)
@JoinTable(
    name = "post_comment_ref",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "post_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "post_comment_id")
)
private List<PostComment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
```

And now, the link table is going to be called `post_comment_ref` and the Foreign Key columns will be `post_id`, for the `post` table, and `post_comment_id`, for the `post_comment` table.

> Unidirectional `@OneToMany` associations are not efficient, so you are better off using bidirectional `@OneToMany` associations or just the `@ManyToOne` side.

Comment: Hi @Vlad, If the join table has no extra column(s), is it better to use the `@JoinTable` instead of the join entity? what is the advantage of the `@JoinTable` over the join entity? (or vice versa)

Comment: Check out [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) and [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/) articles for a detailed answer to your question.

Comment: I've read these articles before; They are great. But my fault, i missed the **Conclusion** part of [second article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/). That part is my answer. Thanks @Vlad.

Comment: When in doubt, just go to Vlad Mihalcea Dot Com. That's where the answers are.

Answer (score 18):

It's the only solution to map a ManyToMany association : you need a join table between the two entities tables to map the association.

It's also used for OneToMany (usually unidirectional) associations when you don't want to add a foreign key in the table of the many side and thus keep it independent of the one side.

Search for @JoinTable in the [hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/) for explanations and examples.

Comment: Hi, It's not the only solution for many to many association. You can create **join entity** with two bidirectional `@OneToMany` associations.

Answer (score 15):

It's also cleaner to use `@JoinTable` when an Entity could be the child in several parent/child relationships with different types of parents.  To follow up with Behrang's example, imagine a Task can be the child of Project, Person, Department, Study, and Process.

Should the `task` table have 5 `nullable` foreign key fields?  I think not...

Answer (score 7):

It lets you handle Many to Many relationship. Example:

```
Table 1: post

post has following columns
____________________
|  ID     |  DATE   |
|_________|_________|
|         |         |
|_________|_________|

Table 2: user

user has the following columns:

____________________
|     ID  |NAME     |
|_________|_________|
|         |         |
|_________|_________|
```

Join Table lets you create a mapping using:

```
@JoinTable(
  name="USER_POST",
  joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"),
  inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="POST_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"))
```

will create a table:

```
____________________
|  USER_ID| POST_ID |
|_________|_________|
|         |         |
|_________|_________|
```

Comment: Question: what if i have already this additional table? The JoinTable wont overwrite the existign one right?

Comment: In my case it's creating a redundant column in the owning side table. for eg. POST_ID in POST. Can you suggest why is it happening?