# Specifying the intermediate table name in JPA OneToMany relationship

Tags: jpa, playframework

I have a table user and each user has a set of other users as friends. the way I defined it in my model class is as following:

```
     Public class User extends Models {
     ....
     @OneToMany
     public List<User> friends;
     .
     .
     }
```

Now the Play JPA is creating an intermediate table name 
user_user with following fields.

```
    mysql> desc user_user;
    ------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | user_id     | bigint(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
    | friends_id  | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |
```

Question is how can i change the name of the intermediate table (user_user) and columns in it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using the `@JoinTable` annotation should give you what you need. There is a good post ( [JPA "@JoinTable" annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478328/jpa-jointable-annotation) ) specifically on how to use this annotation.