# How to insert More then two values in Enum type column in mysql using java?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

In my Java Program Enum like this..

```
public enum WeekdayType {
    MONDAY(Calendar.MONDAY), TUESDAY(Calendar.TUESDAY), WEDNESDAY(
    Calendar.WEDNESDAY), THURSDAY(Calendar.THURSDAY), FRIDAY(
    Calendar.FRIDAY), SATURDAY(Calendar.SATURDAY), SUNDAY(
    Calendar.SUNDAY);

    private int day;

    private WeekdayType(int day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }
}
```

And my Hibernate bean define like this my `TimetableVO.java`

```
    @Column(name="REPEAT_DAYS")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private WeekdayType repeatDays;// And Setter and Getters....
```

In my Service class i'm Doing like this..

```
String totalDays="MONDAY,SUNDAY,FRIDAY,SATURDAY"
    public void createEvent(TimetableVO timetableVO) {
    WeekdayType weekday = null;
    for (String day : totalDays.split(",")) {
        weekday = WeekdayType.valueOf(day);
    }
    timetableVO.setRepeatDays(weekday);
......
......
......
entityManager.persist(timetableVO);     



    }
```

But the Problem is In database column Adding Last Value Only...that mean it Override Previous value

For Ex:above String `SATURDAY` only inserting on Database but i want to insert all values like `MONDAY,SUNDAY,FRIDAY,SATURDAY`...give me Suggestion..

Comment: Correct i want List of Days in my column..but in Hibernate Bean class Define like this private List<WeekdayType> repeatDays; but it is Asking Some relation or Error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your column type

`private WeekdayType repeatDays;`

should be changed to String type

`private String repeatDays;`

set your csv to this column.

Other option is to have

`private List<WeekdayType> repeatDays;`
with `@JoinTable` annotation

which will create another mapping table. to handle manytomany relation.

Comment: But in my Database Column type is Enum.. Is Their any Problem for this?.

Comment: Enum type cannot have multiple enums in it. I suggest change it to String.

Comment: @jointable annotation requires a mapping physical table. you should see thi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478328/jpa-jointable-annotation

Comment: @jointable annotaion need another table But i have only timetable and Their is no table for WeekdayType Enum.

Comment: then you should go for String option mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to save more values in a single column is a conceptual error in a relational database.
A solution could be to create another table, and create a relation between your `TimeTable` and the newly created table.

A second, less flexible alternative, could be create 7 different properties (and also seven different columns) each one relative to a single day, without creating a new table, so you could have:

```
 @Column(name="MONDAY")
 private boolean repeatOnMonday;

 @Column(name="TUESDAY")
 private boolean repeatOnTuesday;

 //...
```