# EJB 3.0 - Entity Relations - javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException

Tags: jpa, entity, ejb-3.0, entity-relationship, many-to-one

I have 2 Entities

1. OrderDetails
2. Orders

In `Orders` I have a `@ManyToOne` relation with another `entity` called `Customer`. In `OrderDetails` I have two `@ManyToOne` relationships which references `Orders` and another entity 'Pizzas`.

I am getting `javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException` exception when I am merging `OrderDetails` entity. But, When I remove `Orders` relation within `OrderDetails` I am able to merge entity smoothly.

Is it not possible to merge an object which has a `ManyToOne` relation with an entity, which intern has a @ManyToOne relation with another entity.

My applicationclient will call a session remote method. which will try to persist OrderDetails like this.

```
    Pizzas pizza = new Pizzas();
    Query pizzaQuery = entityManager.createQuery("select pizza from     Pizzas pizza where pizza.pizzaCode like 'PIZERIA1'");

    pizza = (Pizzas) pizzaQuery.getSingleResult();

    orderSerialNumber = 1;

    Orders orders = new Orders();
    Query ordersQuery = entityManager.createQuery("select order from Orders order where order.orderNumber = 453");
    orders = (Orders) ordersQuery.getSingleResult();

    OrderDetails orderDetails = new OrderDetails();
    orderDetails.setSerialNumber(orderSerialNumber);
    orderDetails.setPizzas(pizza);
    orderDetails.setOrders(orders);
    entityManager.merge(orderDetails);
```

I am getting at while trying to merge.

**STACKTRACE**

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.Ejb3TxPolicy.handleEndTransactionException(Ejb3TxPolicy.java:54)
at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.endTransaction(TxPolicy.java:175)
at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInOurTx(TxPolicy.java:87)
at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:190)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:76)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.java:186)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:41)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.ejb3.BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.invoke(BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.java:67)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationInterceptor.java:67)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.ejb3.stateful.StatefulContainer.dynamicInvoke(StatefulContainer.java:571)
at org.jboss.ejb3.session.InvokableContextClassProxyHack._dynamicInvoke(InvokableContextClassProxyHack.java:53)
at org.jboss.aop.Dispatcher.invoke(Dispatcher.java:91)
at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.AOPRemotingInvocationHandler.invoke(AOPRemotingInvocationHandler.java:82)
at org.jboss.remoting.ServerInvoker.invoke(ServerInvoker.java:891)
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.completeInvocation(ServerThread.java:744)
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.processInvocation(ServerThread.java:697)
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.dorun(ServerThread.java:524)
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:232)
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.commitwhenaborted] [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.commitwhenaborted] Could not commit transaction.
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1435)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:137)
at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75)
at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.endTransaction(TxPolicy.java:170)
at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInOurTx(TxPolicy.java:87)
at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:190)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:76)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.java:186)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:41)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.ejb3.BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.invoke(BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.java:67)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationInterceptor.java:67)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.ejb3.stateful.StatefulContainer.dynamicInvoke(StatefulContainer.java:571)
at org.jboss.ejb3.session.InvokableContextClassProxyHack._dynamicInvoke(InvokableContextClassProxyHack.java:53)
at org.jboss.aop.Dispatcher.invoke(Dispatcher.java:91)
at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.AOPRemotingInvocationHandler.invoke(AOPRemotingInvocationHandler.java:82)
at org.jboss.remoting.ServerInvoker.invoke(ServerInvoker.java:891)
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.completeInvocation(ServerThread.java:744)
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.processInvocation(ServerThread.java:697)
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.dorun(ServerThread.java:524)
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:232)
at org.jboss.remoting.MicroRemoteClientInvoker.invoke(MicroRemoteClientInvoker.java:211)
at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:1724)
at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:629)
at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.InvokeRemoteInterceptor.invoke(InvokeRemoteInterceptor.java:60)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.aspects.tx.ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.ejb3.security.client.SecurityClientInterceptor.invoke(SecurityClientInterceptor.java:65)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invoke(IsLocalInterceptor.java:74)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.PojiProxy.invoke(PojiProxy.java:62)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:207)
at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:164)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.placeOrder(Unknown Source)
at com.client.ApplicationBeansClient.main(ApplicationBeansClient.java:46)
at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.InvokeRemoteInterceptor.invoke(InvokeRemoteInterceptor.java:72)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.aspects.tx.ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.ejb3.security.client.SecurityClientInterceptor.invoke(SecurityClientInterceptor.java:65)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invoke(IsLocalInterceptor.java:74)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.PojiProxy.invoke(PojiProxy.java:62)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:207)
at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:164)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.placeOrder(Unknown Source)
at com.client.ApplicationBeansClient.main(ApplicationBeansClient.java:46)
Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: setRollbackOnly called from:
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.setRollbackOnly(TransactionImple.java:392)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.setRollbackOnly(BaseTransaction.java:195)
at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.setRollbackOnly(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:123)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.markAsRollback(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:421)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:576)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:614)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$1.beforeCompletion(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:513)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:101)
at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:269)
at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:89)
at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:177)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1423)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:137)
at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75)
at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.endTransaction(TxPolicy.java:170)
at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInOurTx(TxPolicy.java:87)
at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:190)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:76)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.java:186)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:41)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.ejb3.BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.invoke(BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.java:67)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationInterceptor.java:67)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.ejb3.stateful.StatefulContainer.dynamicInvoke(StatefulContainer.java:571)
at org.jboss.ejb3.session.InvokableContextClassProxyHack._dynamicInvoke(InvokableContextClassProxyHack.java:53)
at org.jboss.aop.Dispatcher.invoke(Dispatcher.java:91)
at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.AOPRemotingInvocationHandler.invoke(AOPRemotingInvocationHandler.java:82)
at org.jboss.remoting.ServerInvoker.invoke(ServerInvoker.java:891)
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.completeInvocation(ServerThread.java:744)
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.processInvocation(ServerThread.java:697)
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.dorun(ServerThread.java:524)
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:232)
```

**OrderDetails.java**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="P_ORDER_DETAILS")
    public class OrderDetails implements Serializable
    {
        @Id
        private int serialNumber;

        //private Orders orders;

        private Pizzas pizzas;

        public int getSerialNumber()
        {
            return this.serialNumber;
        }
        public void setSerialNumber(int serialNumber)
        {
            this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
        }

    /*  @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="ORDERS",referencedColumnName="ORDER_NUMBER")
        public Orders getOrders()
        {
            return this.orders;
        }
        public void setOrders(Orders orders)
        {
            this.orders = orders;
        }*/

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="PIZZAS",referencedColumnName="PIZZACODE")
        public Pizzas getPizzas()
        {
            return this.pizzas;
        }
        public void setPizzas(Pizzas pizzas)
        {
            this.pizzas = pizzas;
        }
    }
```

**Orders.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="P_ORDERS")
public class Orders implements Serializable 
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="ORDER_NUMBER")
    private int orderNumber;

    @Column(name="CUSTOMER")
    private Customer customer;

    public void setOrderNumber(int orderNumber)
    {
        this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
    }
    public int getOrderNumber()
    {
        return this.orderNumber;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(name="P_CUSTOMER_ORDERS", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="CUSTOMER",referencedColumnName="USERNAME"))
    public Customer getCustomer()
    {
        return this.customer;
    }
}
```

Comment: `javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException` happens for some reason, please post the full stack trace.

Comment: @PredragMaric I have added the stacktrace.

Comment: Are you maybe swallowing some exception in `com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate()`? This stacktrace doesn't provide anything useful.

Comment: No I am not eating any exception.

Comment: @PredragMaric But, a quick question . Is it possible to this. To have a entity relations with another which intern have a relation with other entity.

Comment: Sure, nothing wrong with that. Cascading options just need to be configured properly.

Comment: Okay. will look into that. Can you provide a concrete example .

Comment: For example, if you want to save new `OrderDetails` entity, with new `Orders` instance attached to it, you need to have something like this `@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` in order to save also the related entity. Another thing to check, your `@JoinTable` mapping seems incomplete, take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5482838/4074715) for a clean and complete example.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem and i solved it by creating a server with `all` configuration like illustrated through the below image (probably you have created the server with the `default` configuration).

[image]