# PersistenceException - org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException is thrown when multiple @OneToMany relations with the same entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, corda

In my application I get org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException when I include 2 or more lists of the same entity(@OneToMany relations) in one class.

```
    @Embeddable
    data class DocPresentation(

            @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
            var billOfLadingComments: List<Comment>?,


            @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
            var invoiceComments: List<Comment>?,

            ...
```

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Comment")
    data class Comment(

            @Column(name = "date")
            var date: Date?,

            @Column(name = "message")
            var message: String?,

            @Embedded
            var sender: Company?

    ) {
        constructor() : this(null, null, null)

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name = "database_id")
        var databaseId: Int? = null
    }
```

The relation is unidirectional, so an intermediary table is created which holds the ids of the related entities. In this case it includes the id of the embedding entity of `DocPresentation`, and 2 colums: `billOfLadingComments_database_id` and `invoiceComments_database_id`.
When I comment one of the lists the application works properly. How can I resolve the exception?

Comment: Have you tried to configure these two relations by JoinTable annotation? Look at -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478328/jpa-jointable-annotation.

Comment: Are you using one common JoinTable for 2 OneToMany mappings?

Comment: @oputyk that post helped, I've resolved the error due to the link you've provided. Please post the comment as an answer so I could rate it up and mark as the best answer.

Comment: @Martin'sRun, yeah, I did so. Now I use different JoinTables for each List. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved in this way. I use 2 Join columns as there are 2 IDs in the embedding entity.

```
@ElementCollection
            @CollectionTable(
                    name = "docs_presentation_bill_of_lading_hashes",
                    joinColumns = [
                        JoinColumn(name = "transaction_id", referencedColumnName = "transaction_id"),
                        JoinColumn(name = "output_index", referencedColumnName = "output_index")
                    ]
            )
            @Column(name = "bill_of_lading_hash")
            var billOfLading: List<String>? = null,

            @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
            @JoinTable(
                    name = "doc_presentation_bill_of_lading_comments",
                    inverseJoinColumns = [
                        JoinColumn(name = "bill_of_lading_comment_id", referencedColumnName = "database_id")
                    ]
            )
            var billOfLadingComments: List<Comment>? = null,
```